# Docker Compose and rabbitmq docker image plugins

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I would like to have my customized image based on rabbitmq. That customized image I like to create with docker-compose. I want management plugi started

If I use docker compose as

```
 rabbitmq: # https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq/
 image: rabbitmq:3-management
 ports:
 - 5672:5672
 - 15672:15672
 - 8080:8080
```

it does bring up management plugin.

If I use docker compose

```
version: '2'
services:
# Rabbit service. See https://hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq/ 
  rabbit:  
    container_name: dev-rabbit
    image:  rabbitmq-our:3-management
    build: ./rabbitmq-our
    environment:
     - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=rabbit
     - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=mq
     - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST=my_vhost
    ports:
     - "4369:4369"
     - "5671:5671"
     - "5672:5672"
     - "15672:15672"
     - "8080:8080"
```

and Dockerfile in **rabbitmq-our/** folder such as

```
FROM rabbitmq
```

Then no plugins are started and I am not getting the management console.

How I can specify running that "3-management" plugin in my custom image startup ?

Comment: Maybe something like FROM rabbitmq:3-management.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I've my compose like this and works the RabbitMQ admin plugin.

```
rabbit:
     container_name: dev_rabbit
     hostname: rabbit
     image: rabbitmq:3.6.6-management
     environment:
        - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=user
        - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=user
     ports:
        - "5672:5672"
        - "15672:15672"
```

I take it from the [hub.docker official page](https://hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq/).

Comment: Any idea why my environment variables don't work for user/pass. It defaults to guest/guest still. I copied and pasted what you have above but changed to 3.7.8-management is all.

Comment: @Collin Most likely because you are already run the container without the env vars. Try to rebuild